# Strange behavior of noexcept specifier in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, noexcept

I found a strange behavior of the `noexcept` operator in C++14.
The following code compiles well by both gcc and clang (with --std=c++14 option).

```
// test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#if 1
#define TESTREF(X) X&&
#else
#define TESTREF(X) X const&
#endif

template <class F, class... Args>
struct is_noexcept_callable
    : public std::conditional_t<noexcept(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...)), std::true_type, std::false_type> {};

template <
    class F,
    std::enable_if_t<is_noexcept_callable<F,int>::value,int> = 0
    >
int evalInt(int x, TESTREF(F) f) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<int>(f(x));
}

template <
    class F,
    std::enable_if_t<!is_noexcept_callable<F,int>::value,int> = 0
    >
int evalInt(int x, TESTREF(F) f)
{
    return static_cast<int>(f(x));
}

int id(int x) noexcept { return x; }
int thrower(int x) { throw(0); }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << noexcept(evalInt(1,id))
              << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << is_noexcept_callable<decltype(thrower), int>::value
              << std::endl;
}
```

Executing the result program, I however got different results depending on compilers:

```
$ g++ --std=c++14 test.cpp
$ ./a.out
true
false
$ clang++ --std=c++14 test.cpp
$ ./a.out
false
false
```

I am not sure which is correct according to the standard.

More strangely, if I change the 5th line in the code above to `#if 0` then gcc compiles the code into another differnt program:

```
$ ./a.out
true
true
```

As you see, the second value is changed.
However, it depends only on the `noexcept` specification of `thrower` function that the macro doesn't touch.
Is there any reasonable explanation to this, or is it just a bug?

---

**Edit**

The result is obtained with GCC 7.4.0 and clang 6.0.0 in Ubuntu 18.04 (64bit) package repository.

Comment: Was it intentional that you’re outputting the result of `noexcept(evalInt(…))`, but for the `thrower` function you output `is_noexcept_callable<…>::value` instead (not that this solves the issue)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only reproduce this bug in GCC before version 8. The difference in behavior is due to the `noexcept` specifier being part of the function type in GCC 7's C++14 version (but not Clang's), although this is a C++17 feature. This can be seen if we add partial specializations of `is_noexcept_callable`:

```
template <class... Args>
struct is_noexcept_callable<int(&)(int), Args...>
    : public std::false_type {};

template <class... Args>
struct is_noexcept_callable<int(int), Args...>
    : public std::false_type {};
```

This suddenly [yields two `false`s](https://wandbox.org/permlink/r3wUwl2tHuRDuVIv): GCC retains the `noexcept` attribute on function types, but explicitly *ignores them during template argument deduction*, so that the above specializations are selected, despite error messages showing `noexcept` if we remove definitions:

```
prog.cc:30:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:28:22: error: incomplete type 'is_noexcept_callable<int (&)(int) noexcept, int>' used in nested name specifier
```

---

#### Why does `TESTREF`'s definition affect `is_noexcept_callable`?

The second part of your question is more subtle. Here, the issue is that `is_noexcept_callable` is already instantiated with the relevant type `int(int) [noexcept]` before you use it in `main`, but it has noexcept attached, so that the result of `is_noexcept_callable<int(int), int>::value` is fixed to true.

`decltype(id)` is `int(int) [noexcept]`, where `[noexcept]` is my notation to express GCC's transient exception-specification attached to the function type. Thus `evalInt(1,id)` causes instantiation of

- `is_noexcept_callable<F,int>` where **`F = int(&)(int) [noexcept]`** when `TESTREF = X&&` and
- **`F = int(int) [noexcept]`** when `TESTREF = X const&`

So when you disable the first branch of your if-directive, then `is_noexcept_callable<int(int),int>::value == true` holds after  `noexcept(evalInt(1,id))` is processed, because `id` is noexcept and this propagates down the instantiation chain.

Consequently, the following prints two falses:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << noexcept(evalInt(1,thrower))
              << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << is_noexcept_callable<decltype(thrower), int>::value
              << std::endl;
}
```

Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/YXDYfXwtEwMQkryD

Comment: Thanks for investigation. I checked my code and still have the same results as in the post. It may be version-specific, so I added compiler information to the post.

Comment: It took a little time to understand the behavior correctly, but now I think I do. Anyway, everything is due to GCC-7's inconsistent treatment of exception specification, and hence a kind of bug, right?

Comment: @junology Yes, that is a bug. Use a more recent version!